# Facebook Unity SDK 7.6.0 does not recognize Bolts BFTask.h classes

Tags: xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine, bolts-framework, bftask

First of all I am using Unity 5.4.3.p4 and XCode 6.4 to build my game for iOS. I recently updated my Facebook SDK from 6.2.2 to 7.6.0 because the latter is not really built for Unity 5.x.x, it sometimes fails to login. Since I've updated  the FB SDK, my game won't compile for XCode. Is there compatiblities that I have not read in the docs? I'm stuck with this problem for almost 3 days.

Thanks!

[FacebookSDK/Plugins/iOS/Bolts.framework/Headers/BFTask.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22AOf.png)

Answer (score 1):

FacebookSDK7.6.0 includes Bolts.framework version 1.6.0.

Bolts.framework 1.6.0 requires Xcode7.

https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-ObjC/releases/tag/1.6.0